# Outlook web addin is not visible on desktop Outlook client except for some admin accounts

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-web-addins

We developed an Outlook Web Addin working perfectly in several customers environment.

We are facing an issue in one case :

- the Web Addin has been deployed centrally through the Office 365
  portal on some tests accounts
- the Addin appears on all Outlook
  Webmails (meaning deployment did work)
- the Addin doesn't appear on most desktop clients ; but for
  some it does. The only accounts where it was working are somehow admin
  accounts.

We tried "cross sessions" to see if it could come from the machine itself or the user.

- After an admin (with addin OK) opens a session on a non admin laptop ; we don't see the addin anymore on Outlook Desktop. And once he gets back to his own laptop, the addin never appears again (!).
- After a user (with addin not OK) opens a session on an admin laptop ; we see the addin in Outlook Desktop.

We investigated these aspects to understand the difference between accounts and laptop configuration :

- Versions : Windows  10 | Office 365 MSO | Office 365 ProPlus licences
  | Exchange online | Outlook for Office 365 MSO v 16.0.12527.20612 >>
  eveything much higher than Office web addin prerequisites.
- GPO for IE11 : Protected mode is enabled for everyone ; Enhanced
  Protected Mode is enabled for everyone.
- GPO linked with web addins : the only GPO set is
  `software\policies\microsoft\office\16.0\wef\trustedcatalogs` >
  `disableomexcatalogs` which blocks the Office Store. But the addin is
  hosted by the customer himself.

Once version prerequisites are OK, and GPO also, what should we investigate further ?

Comment: Can the problem computers see ANY Add-ins? (or just your add-in is having issues?)

Are the privacy setttings or connected experiences dialog set so that add-ins are disallowed?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/privacy/optional-connected-experiences and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/account-privacy-settings-3e7bc183-bf52-4fd0-8e6b-78978f7f121b

Comment: Also see: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/outlook-add-ins-and-optional-connected-experiences/

Comment: Yes it is the same with Boomerang, a well known reference Add-in.

Comment: Thanks for the article on the Microsoft Blog !!! Published the day of the question, and looks exactly like what we are facing !

Comment: Please note that this behavior is soon changing, where Outlook add-ins deployed via Centralized Deployment will be available even when optional connected experiences are turned off. More information can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/privacy-and-security#optional-connected-experiences